# Please help me understand an unexpected result when doing arithmetic with functions

Tags: python

How is the answer `1`?

Bit confused with this, can someone explain why for `beta` `y - x` is 2 - 3 rather than `3 - 2`?

What does `alpha(2, 3)` evaluate to:

```
def alpha(x, y):
    return x + beta(y, x)

def beta(x, y):    
    return y - x        # [1]
```

Comment: you have to swap your x y vars when you call beta function !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alpha(2,3)
```

results in the following code being executed:

```
return 2 + beta(3,2)   # (*)
```

The `beta(3,2)` call in turn results in:

```
 return 2 - 3
```

which gives `-1`, so in `(*)` you have `2 + -1`, which is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused by the names in `alpha`; it calls `beta()` with the arguments *swapped*.

Pay close attention to the `x` and `y` in `alpha()`. If it helps, *replace* the arguments with longer names:

```
def alpha(first, second):
    return first + beta(second, first)
```

Filling in the values everywhere gives you:

```
alpha(2, 3)
-> 2 + beta(3, 2)
-> 2 + (2 - 3)
-> 2 + -1
-> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alpha evaluates:

```
x-beta(y,x)=x+x-y=2*x-y.
```

Mind you swapped the parameters of `beta` in the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
   alpha(2,3)
-> 2+beta(3,2)
-> 2+(2-3)
-> 2+2-3 = 4-3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The function arguments swap places:

```
return x + beta(y, x)    <-- y, x
def beta(x, y):          <-- x, y
```

So function call `beta(2,3)` executes `return 2 - 3`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `y` as `x` and `x` as `y`.

In that case `alpha(2, 3)` means `2 + beta(3, 2)` which evaluates to `2 + 2 - 3` which is `1`.